# Can I monitor Asterisk usage with Cacti?

Tags: snmp, asterisk, cacti

I want to be able to see how many minutes of use each user in my asterisk uses.  Right now, I am using a POTS interface to the outside wold, but I want to know how much the system is used, so I can compare an IP-based service.

Ideally, I want to be able to see how much each POTS line is used, in minutes per month.

It seems that Cacti would be great to be able to visualize this usage, but I can't find anything online.  The only things I can find will graph the number of open channels at the time of the polling, which I believe would not reflect calls that were started after one poll and ended before the next.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

http://www.voipphreak.ca/2007/04/16/monitoring-asterisk-14-with-snmp-and-cacti-for-pretty-graphs/

or this

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Cacti

While I don't see anything that directly seems to graph minutes, it does look like several people have had the same idea as you.  Some tinkering might be required.

Hope this helps.